# Rotate image in memory friendly way

Tags: c#, image

I have plenty of huge images (4000x4000px, PNG or JPG), and I want to rotate them by orders of 90°, or shrink them. I do not care about speed (the task can finish in order of seconds), what I do care about is memory consumption.

Is there any (nontrivial?) memory-friendly way on how to do such transformations? I am thinking about streaming -> with BMP, it is pretty straightforward, just read the line, and put pixels to specific locations in file. Language/platform is irrelevant for me (I have current application written in C#).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more *why* you care about memory consumption? Such an image might be on the order of 100 megs in memory; you have 2000 megs available even on 32 bit machines, and hugely more than that on 64 bit machines. And it won't live long. Why are you optimizing to eliminate short-lived large objects from the heap?

Comment: It's not possible to performing a clean JPEG crop unless you are cropping along an MCU (minimum coded unit) line (usually this means the top and left coordinates must be divisible by 8 or 16). So, trying to performing cropping using a streaming operation may be more difficult if your JPEG is slicing through an MCU, since you'll need to recompute all blocks.  If you're interested in block-based JPEG transformations, I encourage you to investigate open-source lossless JPEG transformation libraries (either to use the libraries or to investigate how they work).